# @Mock/@InjectMocks for groovy - spock

Tags: java, groovy, junit, mockito, spock

In JUnit / Mockito we have 2 extremly useful annotations: **@Mock** and **@InjectMocks**.

In my new project i started using groovy with spock for testing, I'm wondering if there is a replacement for mentioned annotations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no real need for `@Mock` in Spock, because there is already `= Mock()`, which can be used everywhere an annotation can be used (and also in other places). There is an open pull request for `@InjectMocks`, but it hasn't been decided if such a feature will make it into spock-core or spock-guice. (Shipping this feature with spock-guice, or at least requiring Guice on the class path, would allow to delegate injection to Guice, rather than reinventing the wheel.) If not, `@InjectMocks` could always be shipped as a third-party Spock extension.

Comment: Is `@InjectMocks` available in any third-party Spock extension?
I miss this feature in Spock.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote an annotation two months ago: https://github.com/msid256/MockInjector4Spock.

> The bean you want to test doesn't need to be instantiated manually. All you need to do is to declare it as a field and annotate it with @InjectMocks.

```
@Service
class ServiceC {
    @Autowired
    public ServiceC(ServiceA a, ServiceB b) {}
}

class DemoSpec extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    ServiceA serviceA;

    ServiceB serviceB = Mock(ServiceB.class)

    @InjectMocks // from MockInjector4Spock - de.github.spock.ext.annotation.InjectMocks
    ServiceC serviceC;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it is not working

Comment: I could be wrong but what about accessing the member of the class under test and assign values directly, as in groovy nothing is private

Comment: I don't think can do with private fields.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/marcingrzejszczak/spock-subjects-collaborators-extension

you can use  `@Collaborator` and `@Subject` instead `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`

Answer (score 0):

In groovy there is no private scope, so we can modify the members of the class under test directly. So we can assign the member to our mocked value.